# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/static' Django file upload issue

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-admin, apache2, mod-wsgi

I recently deployed my django wesite on apache using mod_wsgi. I was testing everything to make sure i can work on more important things without having to go back and fix something. I was uploading a .xlsx file on the django admin and this error came up:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'

This is my `settings.py` `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` line:

```
STATIC_URL = /static/
#STATIC_ROOT = home/alexholst/excelsite/static
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "static")

#STATIFILES_DIR = [
#    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
#]
```

Ive serched online for the past 2 hours to no avail. What could this be?

Answer (score 0):

well your user does not have permission for to write in the static folder.
Add your server user to have access to all of the project folders (recursively)

```
sudo chown -R my_user:my_user /path/to/my/project
```

Comment: should i put in the project or just the static folder in the command

Comment: i tried putting the project itself: /path/to/my/PROJECT, but it didnt work

Comment: put the whole project, because anyway the server user must have access to all of the folders in the project.

Comment: where is your staticfolder

Comment: /home/user/project/static

Comment: okay so when you go `./mange.py collectstatic` django will write the data to the folder you specified in your STATIC_ROOT, if the folder is not in the project then point the command to the static folder :)

Comment: i cant `./manage.py collectstatic`
"-bash ./manage.py: No such file directory"